# How can I get a count of cards in a group in the macOS Contacts app?

Tags: mac, contacts

The Contacts (Address Book) app in macOS has a card count for the "All Contacts" list. If I click on "All Contacts" and scroll to the bottom I can see that count, but it doesn't seem to work in any of my custom groups. I saw a card count at the bottom of one of my group lists, while I was editing the list. But it disappeared and now I cannot see how to view a count of the cards in my groups.

Comment: Might help to mention what version of macOS you're running.

Comment: I'm running El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

For the Contacts app in macOS Sierra (10.12.x), if you select more than one card in a group list, the details pane on the right shows the number of cards selected. So if you hit Cmd-A to "Select All" cards in a group it should show you the total number of cards in the group.

Trying to drag a selected set of cards is another way to see how many cards are selected. The drag icon will have a red badge showing the number of cards being dragged.